# how can i get the title of pickerview to textfied

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am writing an application in which when we click on a textfield it generates a pickerview.
pickerview has two components

now what is my question is i want to get the titles of both the components which are highlighted into my textfield separated by a comma(,)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets says you have a `UIPickerView` object called as pickerView. When the user completes his action and taps the done button, you should get the selected value as

```
int offset1 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
int offset2 = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[arrOne objectAtIndex:offset1],[arrTwo objectAtIndex:offset2]];
```

Where arrOne and arrTwo are the array's used to populate the pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the pickerview delegates then write this snippet under

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    for(NSUInteger k = 0; k < <number of components>s; ++k++)
    {
        NSUInteger selectedRow = [<Your pickerview name> selectedRowInComponent:k];
        NSString *title = [[<Your pickerview name> delegate] pickerView:<Your pickerview name> titleForRow:selectedRow inComponent:i];
       [<Your temporary string> appendFormat:@"Selected item \"%@\" in component %lu\n", title, i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add `UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate` Delegate then in delegate method you can directly assign this value like bellow...

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    yourTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[arr1 objectAtIndex:row],[arr2 objectAtIndex:row]];

}
```

hope this help you...

Comment: wel-come @pradeep :) accept any answer which is the best and helpful to you dude.. Thanx ..